# list 10 maximum commented news in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tabel news and comments:

**news**: newsId, newsTitle, newsDate, newsReadCount

**comments**: ID, newsID, comment, ndate

I have select 10 rows which have maximum read based on value newsReadCount between two dates:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE DATE(newsDate) BETWEEN '20120414' AND '20130414' ORDER BY newsReadCount DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Here, I want to select 10 news with newsTitle, total comment count from news table of between two dates which have maximum comments based on relation newsID of comments table. How can I query this in mysql? Do I need join. Please help me I am new to mysql.

newsID of comments table is the value of news ID primary key of news table.

**Edited:**

select news between two dates with following results

**Results:**

```
| newsTitle  | Total Comments |     
-------------------------------    
| onenews    |  25            |    
| another    |  30            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `join`, a `group by`, an `order by` and a `limit`:

```
SELECT
    news.newsTitle, COUNT(comments.ID) AS `Total Comments`
FROM news INNER JOIN comments ON
    news.newsId = comments.newsID AND news.newsDate BETWEEN '20120414' AND '20130414'
GROUP BY news.newsId
ORDER BY `Total Comments` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

plz see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfb25/14/0).

Comment: can we select all comments of all 10 news with this single query so that I list all 10 news with it's comment using php

Comment: No you can't get both comment count and comment details in the same query. How does that work anyway? for every comment you want to show total count?

Comment: you could use a function called `group_concat` it will look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfb25/18/0

Comment: I used group_concat(comments.ID) result show  [BLOB - 1.0   KiB] in field value instead of 1,3,54,12 in my phpmyadmin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713397/mysql-groupconcat-returning-blob-xxxb-kib

Comment: @codemaniac that's just a 'feature' of PHPMyAdmin. Press the 'T' button above and you should see the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
SELECT n.newsTitle, count(c.ID) as totalCount
FROM   News n LEFT JOIN Comments c ON n.newsId = c.newsID
WHERE  DATE(n.newsDate) BETWEEN '20120414' AND '20130414'
GROUP BY n.newsTitle
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT   10
```

Comment: Why group by newsTitle and not newsId? maybe two news have the same title. Also it is not a good practice to use both `on` and `where` when joining, you could copy `where` clause contents to `on` clause.