# MYSQL Seconds column for time

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatetime

I have a seconds column and I need to display in some readable format.

```
Table A
Time
259200

select Time from Table A
```

and I need to get :
3 days,`00:00:00` I need  to have no of days `if > 24` hrs.

I tried lots of way but I was not able to get the right answer.

A few things which I tried are:

```
select  floor(hour( sec_to_time
Select sec_to_time
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( MAKETIME(
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating relative time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculating-relative-time)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', 
              `time` DIV 86400, 'day(s) and', 
              SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(`time`, 86400)), 'hours'
             ) 
FROM TableName;
```

`time DIV 86400` gives you the number of day(s), ``` SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(``time``, 86400)) ``` gives you the `h:m:s` remaining. Then just concat them.

Output:

```
0 day(s) and 01:50:00 hours
1 day(s) and 10:17:36 hours
101 day(s) and 10:50:32 hours
```

plz see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31a87/4/0).

Comment: +1 for the indentation of and the line breaks in the query. SQL is a language too!

Comment: Thanks Jurgenreza U R Awesome, It works in my sql through command prompt but through sql workbench it gives BLOB and i am using this value in Ireport and even there it prints blob :( any inputs will be a great help

Comment: @user2111815 BLOB problem is not related to mysql. see this post on how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713397/mysql-groupconcat-returning-blob-xxxb-kib

Comment: @user2111815 Click on the check mark on the left side under the score. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for time and date functions. For example, `SEC_TO_TIME` and `TO_DAYS`.

UPDATE:

Quite right, I misread. The following is a terrible hack but should give you the answer you want. For a real system, I would write a proper function for this.

```
concat(floor(hour(sec_to_time(x))/24), " days, ", subtime(sec_to_time(x),concat(floor(hour(sec_to_time(x))/24)*24,":00:00")))
```

Comment: Hi Igelkott, Thanks for the reply but not i was not able to get the days and mm:hh:ss :(